# DNS Puzzle - No MX records but still routes email

Tags: domain-name-system, email

We have a client that the domain name has a cluster of DNS servers serving it but when it comes to mail routing... I've checked several different mx lookups including nslookup and things like who.is and mxtoolbox.com and to confirm the client showed me their DNS records and there are no MX records.

I was wondering .. how can they receiving emails if no MX specified?

The only thing I can think of is if there is a root A record pointing to (what is essentially a LAMP) server does it default back to that (at a stretch)?

Comment: check email routing option in cpanel or any other admin panel which you are using..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `A` record pointing to the mail server handling the mail is enough, [`MX`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record) records are "optional", but preferred. So, if you have a suitable A record, this will be sufficient to deliver the mail.

Comment: So trying a TCP connect (e.g. by using telnet) to an `A` record's IP address at port 25 is sufficient to see whether an SMTP server is available? should I also check other records like e.g. `CNAME` or `AAAA`?

Comment: @UweKeim: It can be sufficient, yes. However, what I omitted is the fact that it's entirely possible to have a mail address `user@example.org` without having an actual A record for `example.com`. In that case, you would *need* the MX record pointing to a valid `A/AAAA` record. Also, if you want to use IPv6, you obviously need to check the `AAAA` record, not the `A` one. Why would you want to check some `CNAME`s and which anyway?

Comment: Thanks, Sven. And sorry, actually I am not _that_ expert in the DNS area. So no `CNAME` checking. alright :-).